# csom to get specified library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, csom

Are there an easy way to retrieve a specified library in a site with CSOM?
I'm in SharePoint Online and for now, I retrieve all library and test depending  title

It's not really performing well because I need to do multiple requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get list by title using

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);

var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Title');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, i gonna try this tomorrow and come back with result

Comment: Hi, i tried this one but i always go to failed method when executequeryasync. Are the re a way to check if it exists (without looping all list because i have lot and lot of subsite)

Comment: Don't you know on which WEB the library is? In order for the above code to work you should pass the correct `siteUrl`.